# Export function from React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to implement a dapp using react js.In my app.js inside the app class, there is a method that I want to export to another module.I tried many options,but none of them worked for me. In the below code, I want to export username().

**App.js Code**

```
export default class SessionStore 
{ 
......  
username () 
    {
    if (!this._user || !this._user.username) return null
    return this._user.username   
    } 
......
}
```

How to import and use username() function to another modules. I am new to reactjs, so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Add a `static` before your function, and use it as `SessionStore.usename()`

Comment: @Veena S are you trying to use that method in other react component?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method static, but can't access props or state in the method. Better write a util function, which accepts user as argument and import in both classes.

### utils.js

```
export const getUserName = (user = {}) => user.username ? user.username : null;
```

### App.js

```
import { getUserName } from '../utils';

export default class SessionStore { 
......  
  username = () => getUserName(this._user);
......
}
```